# The application don't return the correct answer once I choose a button that contains the choices for a question

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

```
private void checkAnswer(String selectChoice, View view) {
    Button selectedButton = (Button) view;
    Question currentQuestion = questionList.get(questionNum);

    if (selectChoice.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(currentQuestion.getCorrectAns()))) {
        // right answer
        selectedButton.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
        scoreNum++;
    } else {
        // wrong answer
        selectedButton.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
        // Set the background tint of the correct answer to green
        switch (currentQuestion.getCorrectAns()) {
            case "A":
                first.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                break;
            case "B":
                second.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                break;
            case "C":
                third.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                break;
            case "D":
                fourth.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                break;
        }

    }

    // Print the correct answer to the console for debugging
    Log.d("CorrectAnswer", "Correct Answer: " + currentQuestion.getCorrectAns());

    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
        selectedButton.setEnabled(true);

        // Reset background tint of all buttons before changing the question
        selectedButton.setBackgroundTintList(null);
        first.setBackgroundTintList(null);
        second.setBackgroundTintList(null);
        third.setBackgroundTintList(null);
        fourth.setBackgroundTintList(null);

        answer = String.valueOf(currentQuestion.getCorrectAns());

        changeQuestion();
    }, 0500);
}
```

In this code, it should turn the button green if I chose the correct answer. If the user chose a wrong button/answer, the button they have selected will turn red and the correct answer will turn to green. I tried to read what the logcat reads from my activity and it gets the answer properly from the firestore but I'm confused why it does not reflect on the buttons?

this is what I use for retrieving the answers

```
firestore.collection("Difficulties").document(selectedDifficulty).collection("questions")
    .get().addOnCompleteListener((OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>) task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            QuerySnapshot questions = task.getResult();

            for(QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : questions){
                Log.d("FirestoreData", doc.getData().toString());
                questionList.add(new Question(
                        doc.getString("Question"),
                        doc.getString("A"),
                        doc.getString("B"),
                        doc.getString("C"),
                        doc.getString("D"),
                        doc.getString("Answer")));
            }

            Collections.shuffle(questionList);
            setQuestion();

        } else {
            Log.e("FirestoreError", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            task.getException().printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(EasyGameplay.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Are you sure the value of currentQuestion.getCorrectAns() is what it should be?